# JScript Timeout trigger <img>

Tags: javascript, html, timeout

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
setTimeout(function(){
document.body.style.background = <img src="1.jpg"</img>
},33);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I was wondering how I can make the image appear after the setTimeout. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
setTimeout(function () {
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('1.jpg')";
}, 33);
```

Comment: Appreciate the test case :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would do it:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    document.body.style.background="url(1.jpg)";
},33);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a3SCB/)**

*Notice that the timeout is given in milliseconds. For a user, 33 milliseconds probably won't make a noticeable difference compared to adding the background straight away through CSS.*

Answer (score 0):

In order to set a background image, you'd need to use the CSS [`background-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-image) property. Given that you're not providing a CSS stylesheet, and that you want to change the property dynamically through javascript, you'll need to use the `style` attribute.

This W3C wiki [Dynamic style - manipulating CSS with JavaScript](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Dynamic_style_-_manipulating_CSS_with_JavaScript#Changing_Element_Styles) has an excellent explanation about the `style` attribute. It has a number of attributes which correspond to CSS attributes. Take into account that CSS property names for the `style` attribute are defined in [CamelCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase), so `background-image` would actually be `backgroundImage`.

So, in order to set the background image dynamically to the `document.body` element, you could use `document.body.style.backgroundImage="url('1.jpg')";`

(Your timer function was already alright)